# upload folders inside a folder to google cloud using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, bucket

Previously I was working in AWS and I am new in Google Cloud, in AWS there was a way to upload directories/folder to bucket. I have done bit of research for uploading directory/folder in Google Cloud bucket but couldn't find. Can someone help me.I would like to upload some folders(not files) inside a folder to google cloud using python.How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to upload file by file the content on each directory and replicate the path that you have locally in your GCS bucket.

*Note: directory doesn't exist in GCS, it's simply a set of the same file path prefix presented as directory in the UI*